# No periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $X$ be a linear focus in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if it exists $\delta>0$ such that $Y$ is a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of class $C^1$ with $sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}\parallel DY(x)\parallel\leq\delta $ then the vector field $X+Y$ does not have any periodic solution.

I think I must apply the Bendixson-Dulac criterium but can't find out how. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Bendixson-Dulac is one way to do it. Since $X$ is a linear field with a focus at $0$,   the divergence of $X$ is a negative constant, $-c$. (Recall that the divergence of linear field is the trace of its matrix).  Let $\delta =c/3$. The divergence of $Y$ does not exceed $2\delta$. Hence, the divergence of $X+Y$ is at most $-c/3<0$ everywhere, which implies there are no closed orbits.